# Google Play Console App Statistics: Not every country where my app is availabe is shown in the stats

Tags: google-play-console

I have published an android app that is currently available in 35 countries.

When I look at the statistic section in the Google Play Console only 18 of the countries are shown in the KPI "Installations" > "All devices" .

In some other KPIs I can see all countries.

How I can access all KPIs for all countries?

Comment: Stupid question: are you sure that you have actual users in the other countries?

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure as I can see many active users in those countries when I go into another KPI @RobbyCornelissen